# mysql increment value based on previous record

Tags: mysql, increment, record

I have a table

```
Id|Parent|Counter
--|------|-------
 1| A    | NULL
 2| A    | NULL 
 3| A    | NULL
 4| B    | NULL
 5| B    | NULL
 6| C    | NULL
 7| D    | NULL
 8| D    | NULL
```

I want to update the table such that the counter column is update (+1) as long as previous `parent = parent`. If not, `counter =1` so:

```
Id|Parent|Counter
--|------|-------
 1| A    | 1
 2| A    | 2
 3| A    | 3
 4| B    | 1
 5| B    | 2
 6| C    | 1
 7| D    | 1
 8| D    | 2
```

I have about 3.5M records.

I can get a select query but can get it to work with update. This is what I have:

```
SELECT  t.Parent, (
  SELECT COUNT( * ) 
  FROM bomitems AS x
  WHERE x.id <= t.id
  AND x.Parent = t.Parent
  ) AS Counter
FROM bomitems AS t
```

Comment: Gotta ask you, have you tried something yet?  This would be a non trivial query for someone to write.

Comment: See my question about my progress sofar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a good and clever query to generate those row numbers, one which avoids a messy solution using session variables.  To do the update, just join your table `bomitems` to this query:

```
UPDATE bomitems t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.Parent,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bomitems AS x WHERE x.id <= t.id AND x.Parent = t.Parent) AS Counter
    FROM bomitems t
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
SET t1.Counter = t2.Counter;
```

I tested this query on my local MySQL Workbench and it appears to be working.